# Apply a different formula for each condition that is met in a certain data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

Lets say that for example I have the following data frame called "df1" (which is actually part of a much larger data frame but this example will do for now):

df1=

```
[,1]    [,2]    [,3]
   1    -0.5     1.3
   1    -0.3     0.9
   5    -0.2     0.2
   2     0.4     0.5
   0     0.5     1.1
   2     1.1     0.1
   1    -0.6     1.8
```

And I have created the following conditions:

```
condA= df1[,2] >= 0 & df2[,3]  > 1
condB= df1[,2] >= 0 & df2[,3] <= 1
condC= df1[,2]  < 0 & df2[,3]  > 1
condD= df1[,2]  < 0 & df2[,3] <= 1
```

Here comes my question:

How do I apply a different function for each condition that is met in df1. For example:

```
If condA is met: df1[,1]=df1[,1]*1
If condB is met: df1[,1]=df1[,1]*2
If condC is met: df1[,1]=df1[,1]*3
If condD is met: df1[,1]=df1[,1]*4
```

Taking into account my example "df1", the output data frame would be like this:

```
[,1]    [,2]    [,3]
   3    -0.5     1.3      # In this row condC is met
   4    -0.3     0.9      # In this row condD is met
  20    -0.2     0.2      # In this row condD is met
   4     0.4     0.5      # In this row condB is met
   0     0.5     1.1      # In this row condA is met
   4     1.1     0.1      # In this row condB is met
   3    -0.6     1.8      # In this row condC is met
```

Help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not clear- is the set of `ifs` an if/elseif, or would `condD` overrule `condA`? Also, do you have only four conditions, or is this a simplified example (and there can be many more conditions?)?

Comment: As David suggests, if all your conditions are disjunct, then looping over `?switch` is a good choice, or possibly a `subset` operation for each condition.

Comment: @ David Robinson: The conditions do not overrule each other as you can see by looking at the ranges the different conditions apply to. In this case the conditions are not a simplified example but I actually use these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take what you wrote above and apply it.

```
condA <- df1[,2] >= 0 & df1[,3]  > 1
df1[condA,1] <- df1[condA,1] * 1
```

(Although, for efficiencies sake you could just skip this one since it doesn't do anything.  I'm also assuming df2 in your question is a typo since you never mention it otherwise.)

One way to make it briefer might be to just make a list out of your conditions and then cycle through.

```
conds <- list(
condA= df1[,2] >= 0 & df1[,3]  > 1,
condB= df1[,2] >= 0 & df1[,3] <= 1,
condC= df1[,2]  < 0 & df1[,3]  > 1,
condD= df1[,2]  < 0 & df1[,3] <= 1)
for(i in 1:4) { df1[conds[[i]],1] <- df1[conds[[i]],1] * i }
```